# How to send XMR from Minergate to Poloniex?

Tags: payment-id, address

sorry total newb here.  I've been mining Monero after seeing the talk at Coinbase.  Really like what you guys are doing.  Now I'm trying to send my XMR from Minergate to Poloniex.  My Deposit address only shows a "Monero Payment ID" but Minergate is asking for both a Monero address and an "optional" Payment ID.  Where do I find the Poloniex deposit address?  Or what are the steps to send from Minergate to Poloniex?  Thanks,

Comment: Be careful with Minergate. They use closed source software and may be connected to scammers: https://monero.stackexchange.com/questions/2930/which-entities-are-related-to-bytecoin-and-minergate

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To see your Monero deposit address on Poloniex click **Show me the Deposit Address** when viewing your payment ID.

Comment: Awesome - not sure how I missed that. Thanks for the quick response.