# Trouble restoring FreeWallet account

Tags: security, third-party-wallets, mobile

Just after updating the FreeWallet app I lost my passwords book.

The FreeWallet app is asking to restore my wallet. I've used the "email restore" option + "forgot password " but I never received the verification code in my email.

Writing to FreeWallet support doesn't work for now, as there's no response (not even notification of complaint record) for 4 days.

What should I do?

Comment: ..i have a similar problem. Did Freewallet in the end answere? How did you make them answere. I cant make contact to them.. would be nice if you can help me.. thanks

Comment: They are terrible!!! I lost 51 Monero which I sent form there wallet which never arrived! I’ve asked them for help again and again with nothing!!

Answer (score 10):

[FreeWallet is a third party, closed source wallet associated with Bytecoin and Minergate where you are not in control of your private keys](https://monero.stackexchange.com/a/2941/145). Therefore the only way to be able to recover your XMR/account is to keep asking them. However it looks like that they are not replying to you.

**The best way to address this is go to the App and submit a review so other people may know. Probably FreeWallet may have to help you.**

Sorry, hopefully you'll be able to recover your account and withdraw your XMR to a real monero wallet. In case you've recovered your account you can create  a wallet here https://moneroaddress.org/ and transfer your XMRs.

Answer (score 1):

I had this issue also. You may need to log in to the app using the mobile sign-in / facebook / google option if you had originally set up your account that way. That worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

Apologies for the delay! We're having an increased number of incoming support requests due to the recent network events, and while our team is adjusting by working extra hours, there could be some delays with replies.

How did you create your account with Freewallet? If you used a phone number, Google+ or Facebook account, you didn't set a password, so there's nothing to restore. Please log in using the same authorization method you had for your wallet.

If you need step-by-step assistance, please provide your user id: our support reps will get back to you. Thanks!

**UPD:** Mic, please provide your user id so that we could review your transaction and get back to you. Looking forward to hearing from you!

Comment: But how do I provide my user id, if I cannot login to my account?

Comment: Todor, if you don't remember your user id, please contact our support team and provide additional details on your account (such as your email or a phone number associated with it, etc.), and our reps will help you restore the access to your wallet.